# Select from another table taking the result from one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Coding away as usual - and this may seem like a very simple thing to ask but bear with me since I am picking up MySQL on my own and trying to use it to it's ultimate power can take some time!

So my question is this - I have a search query, and what I want to do is take a column result from the original query and pull back another table on it. Sounds simple enough in theory I think, but I just can't seem to make it work!

The column is called 'package_Id'. Basically, if the column called 'package_Id' has the value of 'CUSTOM', I want to search one table, and if it's not 'CUSTOM', I want to search another table. There are three tables, one called p2s_2_shipping, and the other two called custom_packages and packages.

```
 SELECT package_Id FROM p2s_2_shipping WHERE p2s_shipping.Id = '$p2sId' AND...
```

This is where I am stuck. Something along the lines of (pseudo-code time!)...:

```
IF package_Id = 'CUSTOM', SELECT * FROM custom_packages WHERE custom_packages.Id = '$p2sId' ELSE SELECT * FROM packages WHERE package.Id = '$p2sId'.
```

Comment: How different are the tables?

Comment: The first table is completely different from the second two. Packages and Custom_Packages are similar, but packages has many more columns. The data I want to return from the select on either of the two packges tables, however, will be similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM custom_packages WHERE custom_packages.Id = '$p2sId' AND '$package_Id' = 'CUSTOM'
UNION
SELECT * FROM packages WHERE package.Id = '$p2sId' AND '$package_Id' != 'CUSTOM'
```

Note that a UNION of two or more SELECT clauses need to have the same number of corresponding columns in each query, so you may need to modify the `*` to be more specific about the columns you are expecting.

**UPDATED**

If you want to tie this to another table, you can use a LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       COALESCE(t2.col1, t3.col1) AS col1, 
       COALESCE(t2.col2, t3.col2) AS col2,
       // you'll need to do this for each column from t2/t3 that you want..
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.some_id = t1.some_id AND t1.some_column = 'custom'
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.some_id = t1.some_id AND t1.some_column != 'custom'
```

Comment: Hmmm. How would I tie this into the original query? I just want to make one query that ties the results from the first table to the corresponding 2nd table that fits. So, select*from t1 and (select*from t2 if t1.column = 'custom' OR select*from t3 if t1.column = 'anything else'(

Comment: @aamirl: First off, stop with the `SELECT *` crap.  :)  Be picky about what fields you're getting, and things will be easier (and possibly faster!) for you in the long run.

Comment: Good point - but I was just using SELECT * to make the question more readable. :) Which fields are picked by the two select statements shouldn't have too much of an effect on the original query and question, which is to try to figure out how to use the results of one query to search another table (at least that's my understanding!)

Comment: @aamirl:  Ahh.  I usually use something like `SELECT ...a bunch of fields...` to indicate such things in examples.  Makes it clear that you're getting specific fields rather than shotgunning it.  :)

Comment: @PinnyM: You need to add the ID to the join conditions as well, right?

Comment: @aamirl: yes, I did that - didn't I?

Comment: @cHao: Nope, you just needed to refresh your page :)

Comment: @PinnyM - Thanks for the efforts! Really appreciate it. I am still not sure if this is what I am looking for though. If the column from the original select is 'CUSTOM', I want to query one table, and if it is NOT custom, I want to query another table. It seems as if this join sequence queries both tables. Does that make sense? I guess it could be explained just by an If, Else block: If t1.package_Id = 'CUSTOM' {SEARCH TABLE 2}, ELSE {SEARCH TABLE 3}. Maybe I am not being clear =/

Comment: @cHao : Thanks! Will keep that in mind for future questions :)

Comment: @aamirl: This is indeed looking in both tables, or at least pretending to.  But what will happen is that the "CUSTOM" -- or whatever other value -- will cause one of the join conditions to never be true, and that join's fields will all be null due to how left joins work.  The other join will match, assuming there is a matching row in the other table.  And the `COALESCE` stuff picks the fields from the join that   matched.

Comment: @PinnyM Whoa, finally just got around to evaluating this. Thank you so much for the continuous back and forth help! It definitely worked.

Comment: @cHao And thank you for clarifying things - it really helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but the pseudocode you have given above can easily be written in SQL using `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END` construct. To make use of it, you can first join all the 3 tables together and then based on `package_ID` values, you can **selectively** choose the columns from one of the two tables.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN s.package_Id = 'CUSTOM' THEN p.column1 ELSE cp.column1 END 
FROM p2s_2_shipping s  
LEFT OUTER JOIN custom_packages cp ON s.some_id = cp.some_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN packages p ON s.some_id = p.some_id
```